# Views and downloads count - Update database on view with lightbox and download

Tags: laravel, fancybox, counter

I've made a site with laravel and have a page where there are pictures that can be seen in hi-resolution via fancybox or downloaded. In the database i have counters for each action. and I do already have GET routes set up for the counting since they are used in other situations too.

for example: www.mysiste.com/somecode/someothercode/image/viewed

the simplified structure of each image is this.. This is called inside a for each loop.. i removed all styling and classes for better reading...

```
<div >
    <div class="card" style="background-color: lightgray">
        <div >
            <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="/images/......../{{$photo->filename}}">
                <img class="card-img" src="/images/......../thumb/thumb_{{$photo->filename}}">
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="card-footer">
            <div>
                <div>
                    <a download="{{$photo->filename}}" href="/images/......../{{$photo->filename}}">
                        <span>Download (Hi-Res)</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a download="social_{{$photo->filename}}" href="/images/......../social_{{$photo->filename}}">
                        <span>Download (Social-Res)</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would need that when they hit the download button it calls a certain URL in the background for upcounting.. (most important)

If possible I would like to hit another URL when the images are viewed fullscreen through fancybox.

how can this be done?

Comment: Change your a tag href to controller function that will increment your download count and return the image

Comment: The controller function does only count.. it does not return a download link because it is used in other places too.. I'm currently trying to do it with vue and axios... that should work.. but I still have no clue about the fancybox part

Comment: For fancybox part, you could use `afterShow` callback to make ajax request to some page where you update view count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something in the lines of:

```
    <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="{{ route('photo.fancybox', ['photo' => $photo])}}">
        <img class="card-img" src="/images/......../thumb/thumb_{{$photo->filename}}">
    </a>

...

    <a href="{{ route('photo.download', ['photo' => $photo])}}">
        <span>Download (Hi-Res)</span>
    </a>
```

PhotoController

```
    public function download(Photo $photo){
       $photo->downloadCount->increment();
       return redirect('/images/......../'. $photo->filename);
    }

    public function fancybox(Photo $photo){
       $photo->fancyboxCount->increment();
       return redirect('/images/......../social_'. $photo->filename);
    }
```

And make sure to register your new routes accordingly:

```
Route::get('photo/download', 'PhotoController@download')->name('photo.download');
Route::get('photo/fancybox', 'PhotoController@fancybox')->name('photo.fancybox');
```

Comment: thanks, this solves the download counter thing, but not the view counter.. do you have a solution for that too?

Comment: If you mean for the FancyBox view, you could create another function in the same idea. Let me update my code

Comment: that solves the issue for the first clicked imag,e but not if they go to the next picture with the left/right arrow..

Comment: as long as the `href` for all your fancybox Pictures in your Carrousel are calling the controller, it will work

Comment: give me a half an hour and i report back.. thank you for your help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212603/discussion-between-sharkyenergy-and-christophe-hubert).

Comment: please join the chat